# Installing Gitlab on local machine. Database migration fails on Debian 9

Tags: postgresql, debian, gitlab-ci

I am trying to install Gitlab on Debian 9 and I am getting the next error in my log file of PostgreSQL:

> 2019-07-12_07:49:46.95528 LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
>   2019-07-12_07:49:47.28220 LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-07-04 09:45:13 GMT
>   2019-07-12_07:49:47.28250 PANIC:  could not flush dirty data: Function not implemented
>   2019-07-12_07:49:47.36949 LOG:  startup process (PID 7236) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
>   2019-07-12_07:49:47.36956 LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
>   2019-07-12_07:49:47.47543 LOG:  database system is shut down

I run sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure and get the next error:

There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

> bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] (gitlab::database_migrations line 53) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
>   ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/chef-script20190712-99-n1onh3" ----
>   STDOUT: rake aborted!
>   PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>           Is the server running locally and accepting
>           connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:55:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in`load'
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `'
>   Tasks: TOP => gitlab:db:configure
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
>   STDERR:
>   ---- End output of "bash"  "/chef-script20190712-99-n1onh3" ----
>   Ran "bash"  "/chef-script20190712-99-n1onh3" returned 1

When I run: sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
I get: [ ok ] Restarting PostgreSQL 11 database server: main.

I tried to remove the PID file, but I can not locate it. It said that does not exist.

What do I not see in order to make the reconfiguration of Gitlab complete?

Comment: There should be nothing to migrate if you are installing a new instance. Maybe file a bug against Gitlab.

Comment: Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[migrate gitlab-rails database]' : That is the reason that I think that migration of gitlab-rails database fails.